# Using find and cat to duplicate the content of multiple files

Tags: bash, duplicates, find, cat

Dears,

I have tried a combination of "find" and "cat" in a bash script to duplicate contents of hundreds of files in sub-directories:

```
find ./inlet3/* -type f -name 'U' -exec bash -c 'cat "{}"' \; > temp -exec bash -c 'cat temp >> "{}"' \;
```

Looking at the given command, I intend to first copy the content of each "U" into a temporary file named "temp", which is supposed to be created each time in the directory where the bash script exists. This part should be achieved by the following method:

```
-exec bash -c 'cat "{}"' \; > temp
```

The content of "temp" should be subsequently appended to "U", to have a file with duplicated content. This part is supposed to be done by the given method:

```
-exec bash -c 'cat temp >> "{}"' \;
```

However, the command does not give me the desired result. I would anticipate that for each "U" found via find, "temp" would be overwritten. But I see that the content of previously found "U"s are appended to "temp", accumulating its content. If I try to remove "temp" with the following method:

```
-exec rm -rf temp \;
```

then I will receive an error:

> cat: temp: No such file or directory

There are some other -exec options that I have omitted for simplicity.

Could anybody say where I might be wrong? I appreciate any hint.

Kind regards.

Comment: You want `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to create the temp file in the same directory as U.

Comment: Won't the unquoted `> temp` just send all output from `find` into `temp` wherever you are logged when you run it? Possibly buffered? I think maybe you means it to be inside the `"cat {}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to create the temp file in the same directory as U. And the redirection should be in the bash session: in fact all the shell operations can be run in the same shell:

```sh
find ... -execdir sh -c 'temp=$(mktemp) && cat "{}" > "$temp" && cat "$temp" >> "{}" && rm "$temp"'
```

If you install the `moreutils` package, you can use `sponge` without needing to create a temp file:

```sh
find ... -execdir sh -c '{ cat "{}"; cat "{}"; } | sponge "{}"'
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I took your first suggestion and it worked! I have now faced another issue, "sed: couldn't open temporary file ./inlet3/9.946/sedU0yVQf: Too many open files". I know this should be related to: -exec sed -i '1,3d' {} \; or -exec sed -i '$ d' {} \; both I have used in the same command with find. Is this a leak problem?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, we say

```
echo foo > bar
```

`echo` sees `foo` as it's argument, and sends it to stdout, which we have redirected to `bar`... but it doesn't have to be written this way. In fact, `echo` doesn't even know its output has been redirected. That's the parser handling the streams, so the result means you can write the command in some weird ways -

```
echo > bar foo
```

also works, as done

```
> bar echo foo
```

This is counter-intuitive, but nonetheless true.

Your command was

```
find ./inlet3/* -type f -name 'U' -exec bash -c 'cat "{}"' \; > temp -exec bash -c 'cat temp >> "{}"' \;
```

This is functionally the same as

```
find ./inlet3/* -type f -name 'U' -exec bash -c 'cat "{}"' \; -exec bash -c 'cat temp >> "{}"' \;  > temp
```

or

```
> temp find ./inlet3/* -type f -name 'U' -exec bash -c 'cat "{}"' \; -exec bash -c 'cat temp >> "{}"' \;
```

Accordingly, all output from the `find` is going into `temp`.

What you wanted was

```
find ./inlet3/* -type f -name 'U' -exec bash -c 'cat "{} >| temp"' \; -exec bash -c 'cat temp >> "{}"' \;
```

Unless you `set -o noclobber` the result of `>` is functionally identical to `>|`, but I tend to be explicit when I want truncation. It never hurts.

As Glenn Jackman pointed out, fewer subshells is also better, so -

```
find ./inlet3/* -type f -name 'U' -exec bash -c 'cat "{}" >| temp && cat temp >> "{}"' \;
```

Comment: For comparison, Glenn's excellent answer will have `find` create and clean up a distinct `temp` in every directory where it finds a file named `U`. My answer above will create a single file in the logged directory and tuncate/overwrite it each time, and I didn't clean it up after. Both are neat tricks to learn. He's also right that it's better to do it all in one subshell per hit - I'll steal that tidbit. ;)